# React Native Bundle download screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app. I would like to show a loading screen while [Downloading JavaScript Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUQsU.png) instead of blank white screen, in both iOS and Android. Is it possible to do it in RN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screen is only displayed in the emulator. It is not displayed in the productive app (app already compiled). You can edit the loading screen (Splash Screen). For example with Expo https://docs.expo.dev/guides/splash-screens/